# What is the maximum number of validators in Ethereum?

Tags: ether, proof-of-stake, economics, beacon-chain, validators

I'm wondering how many validators can be maxed out in Ethereum 2.0 Proof of Stake algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of validators in Ethereum depends on the total supply of Ethereum.

Each validator needs to stake 32 ether (ETH).

If there's around 100M ether staked, that would be 3M validators.

The total supply of Ethereum will vary because EIP 1559 will burn ETH, and Proof of Stake replacing Proof of Work will reduce the amount of ETH created per block.

Justin Drake, Ethereum Researcher, discusses the supply in [Modeling Ultra Sound Money](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQTZSb3Rc9I).  His [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZN444__qkPWPjMJQ_t6FfqbhllkWNhHF-06ivRF73nQ/edit#gid=0) from his [tweet](https://twitter.com/drakefjustin/status/1386670011742306310).

Comment: How is it possible to have so many validators?
After all, the number of TCP connections is limited. The more connections, the slower the transmission of packets.

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming that all validators are peered with each other? Found this which some information on how to get the peer count of different validators https://notes.ethereum.org/@djrtwo/eth2-launch-metrics#Relevant-http-endpoints